# How to install gcc cross compiler

Tags: c, mips, cross-compiling

I'm having difficult while trying to install a cross compiler under linux.
I downloaded a toolchain that seems to be ok but what's next ? what orders I need to type in the console to make it to be installed ?

The purpose is to convert a C code to MIPS (little endian) code.

Actually I need it once for only 2 codes, so if someone can only show me those codes in MIPS, I will be more than happy...

**first code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 128

int main ()

{
    char mychar , string [SIZE];
    int i;
    int count =0 ;  

    printf ("Please enter your string: \n\n");
    fgets (string, SIZE, stdin);

    printf ("Please enter char to find: ");
    mychar = getchar();

    for (i=0 ; string[i] != '\0' ; i++ )
        if ( string[i]  == mychar )
            count++;

    printf ("The char %c appears %d times\n" ,mychar ,count);


    return 0;
}
```

**second code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void SIFT(int x_arr[ ], int y_arr[]);

int main ()
{
    int x[20] = {0} , y[20] = {0};
    int m=0,temp=0,curr=0,i=0,j=0;

    printf("Please enter your numbers now:\n\n");

    /*enter numbers one by one. if x[i+1] value < x[i] value, err msg.
      when user want to end the series he must enter '0' which means end of string (it wont       included in x[]) */
    while ( (scanf("%d",&temp) ) != 5 )
    {
        if (temp >= curr)
        {
            x[i] = temp;
            curr = temp;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The numbers are not at the right order !\n\nProgram will now terminate...\n\n");
        }
    }

    SIFT(x,y);

    for (i=0 ; y[i]=='0' ; i++) /*strlen(y) without ('0')'s includes*/
        m++;

    /*Prints  m , y's organs*/
    printf("\n\nm = %d",m);
    printf("Y = ");
    while (y[j]!='0')
    {
        printf ("%d ,",y[j]);
        j++;
    }

return 0;
}

void SIFT(int x_arr[ ], int y_arr[])
{
    int i=0,j=0;

    while (x_arr[i] != '0')
    {
        if (x_arr[i] == x_arr[i+1]) /*if current val. equals next val. -> jump dbl at x_arr*/
        {
            y_arr[j] = x_arr[i];
            i+=2;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            y_arr[j]=x_arr[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }    

}
```

Comment: you don't convert code to mips, but compile it - try running something like 'mips-gcc'. or try listing files that are in archive in toolchain

Comment: tried both, found nothing... maybe you got one and can compile only 2 codes for me ?

Comment: sorry, I don't - give archive name/location  and distribution

Comment: archive name is: crosstool-0.43.tar

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be trying to generate a MIPS homework assignment, now would you?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using [crosstool-NG](http://ymorin.is-a-geek.org/projects/crosstool) to build and install a toolchain for your system.

Comment: Have you looked at the [usage instructions](http://ymorin.is-a-geek.org/projects/crosstool#download_and_usage)? they aren't very complex

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you but I've compiled your source files using ecc (http://ellcc.org) and got:

```
http://pastebin.com/keDPEcsc
```

and

```
http://pastebin.com/zQBsMVfS
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: And I'm sorry if this is a homework assignment. 1. I didn't use gcc, and 2. I compiled for big endian mips. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you need to build you own version with toolchain - it is not a compiler on it's own, it will make one. look at http://www.kegel.com/crosstool/crosstool-0.43/doc/crosstool-howto.html